# How to fit discrete data that have mode 0 to a log-normal distribution?

Tags: r, distributions, discrete-data, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to figure out how to fit a log-normal distribution to discrete data that have mode 0, in particular, without first removing the zeros. For example, paper citation data are said to be log-normal at their core, when separating out confounding factors, in particular, journals and years (unless the steady-state for that Journal has been reached; see [Wang 2013](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/342/6154/127.short), p. 128f and Supp. Mat., p. 6ff; and [Stringer 2008](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0001683), Methods (p. 5f), with the model itself on p. 2, Eq (3)).

Now, all available methods in R I could find that pretend to fit discrete data to a log-normal distribution ask for data that has no zeros. This is  because they all use the native, but continuous `lnorm` implementation and assume the observed data should be rounded to the nearest integer, which makes it impossible to work with zeros (because you'd have a `ln -0.5` in there). Even if you were to just assume the data are rounded using *floor*, you'd still need to deal with `-Inf` from `ln 0`. But many discrete, power-like data sets have a mode of zero and a mean log close to zero, so removing those zeros would clearly eliminate the data's log-normality.

Therefore, my question is:
How do I correctly fit a log-normal to discrete data **with** zeros in it and, in particular, how is that done in R?

#### Addendum

Here is a simple example case in R that seems to show my problems and how I am currently trying to (obviously unsuccessfully) circumvent the "zero-problem" by adding some random noise in the [0,1] range:

```
gamma = 0.5 # added, according to @Glen_b's comment
# (although this issue occurs without gamma, too)
x = floor(rlnorm(1000) + gamma)
# add noise to avoid -Inf for zeros
log.x = log(x + 1 - log(runif(length(x), 0, exp(1))))
mean(log.x) # ensure no 0 is left (used [0,1], not (0,1] above)
# [1] 0.5412944
ecdf.x = ecdf(x)
# note how the (black) fitted model...
plot(0:20, plnorm(0:20, meanlog = mean(log.x),
     sdlog = sd(log.x)), type="l", ylim=c(0,1))
# ...is way of the red (empirical) model
lines(0:20, ecdf.x(0:20), col=2)
```

Comment: I never saw a log-normal fit to data with mode equal to zero. I'd use a power law discrete distribution instead.

Comment: "*paper citation data are said to be log-normal at their core*" -- said by *whom*? What does that even *mean*? There's no "discrete lognormal". Do you mean a lognormal rounded to integers or something else? You might consider whether it might make more sense to fit a distribution actually useful for count data.

Comment: Well, Stringer in his paper claims to have a version in C that they did not make available (see "Methods, Estimating mu, sigma, and gamma for a journal" in the linked paper above). As far as I understand, they fit the normal distribution of the log-corrected data and then project that back into the log-normal distribution. But I am not sure that is indeed the case or how it is done, because they (sadly enough) do not make their actual code available...

Comment: We should be able to understand the question without reading the papers. Expecting people to read *two* papers to follow the question is not reasonable. Please put any relevant quotes that support the claims into the question. At the very least, say where (page numbers and approximate location on page) the parts you think are most relevant are to be found.

Comment: Stringer et al's actual model appears to be given in eqn 3 in the paper. The arbitrariness of the choice of model is made clear in the text near there.

Comment: Right. So, for example, with `floor(rlnorm(100))`, how can I correctly estimate the parameters for the distribution generated from this output data?

Comment: The model is not simply floored. The impact of the shift parameter is important.

Comment: Yes, and the fact that for my empirical CDF with P[X<=x] at my zero (mass) I have the P that corresponds to the relative number of zeros in my data, but any attempt at a fitting my CDFs always end up assigning zero probability (density...) to X=0, so I am always way off (relative to the empirical CDF) with my fits for the first few counts is bugging me, too.

Comment: I think it is important to note that while the pointer to the citations is interesting, I am not looking necessarily for a solution following Stringer or Wang, or using a different distribution; Rather, I am trying to find an answer to what the title says, independent of all that discussion here: How can one fit discrete data with zeros to a log-normal?